# how to close popup window when I called it in other function

Tags: angularjs

I'm defined $modal.open({{..}) in function A and return the result.
then I'm using it in other function and i want to close the popup window in the other function..how I do it?

**For example :**

```
    function A( x, y)
       {
        var a = $modal.open({{..})
        return a.result ;
    }

    function B ( z,w,t)
    {

    // using function A to open the modal
        A(x1, y1).then( 
            function (result1){
            // I want to close the popup window here
        });

}
```

Comment: `var a = $modal.open({{..})` dont you think it is missing one curly close brace?

Comment: This is not the problem.
Usually after the modal .open i do straight the result.then -> and that close the window but now i use it in other function and it's not close me the window

Comment: Which library for $modal you use? ui-bootstrap?

Comment: yes i am using it

Comment: You can close modal instance if you store modal instance in some var outside the function A, and then just call modalInstance.$close().

Comment: Im using it in the Controller of the window popup when i click on the button but isn't close the window.

Comment: Function B called when you click on button inside popup?

Comment: And it should close popup, right?

Comment: Im using function B  for open the window by call function A and the i click on the button and then i want it to close...like in the example:
 A(x1, y1).then( -> in the then the window need to be close

Comment: In function A, just `return $modal.open({ ... });` then in B you can do `var a = A(x1, y1).then(function() { a.close(); });`

Comment: It's throw exception: a.close is not function.
I don't understand why the close on the button in the controller don't close it

Comment: I found that in first time i clicked in the button it's not close BUT in the second clicked the window closed.

Answer (score 0):

We have added "**isOpen**" variable, **by default false**. when user will call function A, then **true** value will assign to this.
whenever user will call the another function, we are checking to isOpen value, then model object will be close.
You can try for this:

```
var isOpen=false;
function A( x, y)
   {
    var a = $modal.open({{..});
    isOpen=true;
    return a.result ;
}

function B ( z,w,t)
{
    A(x1, y1).then( 
        function (result1){
        if(isOpen){
        $model.close(); // close popup window here:
        }
    });
```

}